# Must we Have a video file with multiple quality for play in video.js with quality selector?

Tags: reactjs, video.js

Is it possible to have one video file and when a user plays it changing the quality is possible?

I'm using video.js in react

Answer (score 1):

You need HLS (m3u8) for adaptive streaming, which Video.js supports. It's not a single file but a combination of text files that describe the video and audio variants, and segmented media.

Comment: Is there any perfect documentation that explain the methods? I haven't found yet